# UNIX (AIX) Command Help - Sed & Awk

Tags: unix, awk, sed, command, aix

I'm running this on an **AIX 6.1.**

The intended purpose of this command is to display the following information in the following format:

*GetUsedRAM*:*GetUsedSwap*:*CPU_0_System*:*CPU_0_User*:*…CPU_N_System*:*CPU_N_User*

The command is composed of several sub commands:

```
echo `vmstat 1 2 | tr -s ' ' ':' | cut -d':' -f4,5,14-15 | tail -1 | sed 's/\([0-9]*:[0-9]*:\)\([0-9]*:[0-9]*\)/\1/'``mpstat -a 1 1 | tr -s ' ' '|' | head -8 | tail -4 | cut -d'|' -f 25,27 | awk -F "|" '{printf "%.0f:%.0f:",$2,$1}' | sed '$s/.$//'| sed -e "s/ \{1,\}$//"| awk '{int a[10];split($1, a,":");printf("%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7])}'`
```

Which I'll re format for clarity:

```
echo \
`vmstat 1 2 |
    tr -s ' ' ':' |
    cut -d':' -f4,5,14-15 |
    tail -1 |
    sed 's/\([0-9]*:[0-9]*:\)\([0-9]*:[0-9]*\)/\1/' \
` \
`mpstat -a 1 1 |
    tr -s ' ' '|' |
    head -8 |
    tail -4 |
    cut -d'|' -f 25,27 |
    awk -F "|" '{printf "%.0f:%.0f:",$2,$1}' |
    sed '$s/.$//' |
    sed -e "s/ \{1,\}$//" |
    awk '{int a[10];split($1, a,":");printf("%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7])}' \
`
```

I understand all of the **tr**, **cut**, **head** **tail**, and (roughly) **vmstat/mpstat** commands. The first **sed** is where I get lost, I've tried running the command in smaller segments and not quite sure why it seems to work as a whole but not when I truncate the command before the next **tr**.

I'm also not so sure on the **awk** command although I understand the premise vaguely, as a function allowing formatted output.

Similarly, I have a vague understanding of sed being a command allowing certain strings/characters being replaced in some file.

I'm not able to make out what this specific implementation in the above case is.

Could anyone provide some clarity or direction as to exactly what is happening at each **sed** and **awk** step within the context of the entire command?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `\`\`mpstat -a 1 1` part at the end of the first `sed` command makes no sense and I'm surprised it's not giving you syntax errors - what is it intended to do? Oh hang on - you didn't expand your one-liner properly. I'll edit it to fix that for you.

Comment: OK, I've done that but now - that last awk command MUST be giving you a syntax error, right? The statement `int a[10]` seems to be trying to declare an array `a` of size 10 that contains integers but you don't declare awk variables and the word `int` is the name of an awk function, not a type (all awk scalar vars are of type "numeric string"). Honestly, the whole command line is a mushy mess and should be discarded in favor of a single awk command - if you show us sample input (the output of the vmstat and mpstat commands) and the associated desired output we could help you.

Comment: You need to narrow the scope of the question, or make it more precise.  If you are wondering what `sed 's/\([0-9]*:[0-9]*:\)\([0-9]*:[0-9]*\)/\1/` does, then you should just ask about that.

Comment: How about `man sed ; man awk`? Or – better – read documentation from the net.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the edit. The intended purpose is to display Ram usage, Swap Usage, and Cpu Usage information in a fixed format. That format being the one displayed on the third line of this question.
E.g. 542067:173374:0:0:35:0:0:0:0:0 being the output I get from the full command.

Running the command as a whole doesn't produce syntax errors but in certain segments does. 

I agree that the statement is a mess but it's what I've been provided with.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I have narrowed it, to the sed and awk commands...

Comment: @PJTraill documentation gave enough to understand ambiguously, this  case is too specific and I didn't write it.

Answer (score 0):

## Simplification

This two simpler commands will get the exact same output:

```
# GetUsedRAM:GetUsedSwap:CPU_0_System:CPU_0_User:…CPU_N_System:CPU_N_User

# Select fields 4,5 of last line, and format with :
comm1=`vmstat 1 2 |
        awk '$4~/[0-9]/{avm=$4;fre=$5} END{printf "%s:%s",avm,fre}'
       `
# Select fields 27 (sy) and 25 (us) for four cpu, print as decimal.
comm2=`mpstat -A 1 1 |
        awk -v firstline=6 -v cpus=4 '
             BEGIN{start=firstline-1; end=firstline+cpus;}
             NR>start && NR<end   {printf( ":%d:%d", $27,$25)}'
       `

echo "${comm1}${comm2}"
```

## Description.

Description of original commands

The whole command is the concatenation of two commands.

1. The first command:

The [output of the vmstat is shown in this link](http://aix4admins.blogspot.com/2011/09/vmstat-t-5-3-shows-3-statistics-in-5.html).
The columns 4 and 5 are 'avm' and 'fre'. The output in columns 14 and 15,
seem to be 'us' (user) and  'sy' (system). And I say seem as no output
from the user is available to confirm.

```
The first command
`vmstat 1 2 |               # Execute the command vmstat.
    tr -s ' ' ':' |         # convert all spaces to colon (:).
    cut -d':' -f4,5,14-15 | # select fields 4,5,14,and 15
    tail -1 |               # select last line.
    sed 's/\([0-9]*:[0-9]*:\)\([0-9]*:[0-9]*\)/\1/' \ # See below.
`
```

The sed command selects inside braces all digits `[0-9]*` before a colon
repeated twice. And then again (without the last colon). That's the whole
string in two parts: « (dd:dd:)(dd:dd) » (d means digit).
And finally, it replaces such whole string by what was selected inside
the first braces `/\1/`.
All this complexity just removes fields 14 and 15 as selected by cut.

A simpler command with exactly the same output is:

```
Select fields 4,5 of last line, and format with (:).
`vmstat 1 2 | awk '
     $4~/[0-9]/{avm=$4;fre=$5} END{printf "%s:%s:",avm,fre}'
`
```

2. The second command:

The output of mpstat -A is similar to [this one from Linux](http://www.unixmantra.com/2013/05/24-iostat-vmstat-and-mpstat-examples-for-unix-performance-monitoring.html).
And also similar to this [AIX mpstat -d output](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aixpert/entry/mpstat_d_and_the_undocumented_stats133?lang=en).

However, the exact output of AIX 6.1 for `mpstat -a` (ALL) on the computer
used could have several variations. Anyway, guided by the intended final
output desired: CPU_0_System:CPU_0_User:…CPU_N_System:CPU_N_User.

It seems that the columns to be selected should be `us` (user) and `sy`
(sys) percent of time that used the cpu for all cpu in use,
which seem to be four on the computer measured.

The [manual for AIX 6.1 mpstat is here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/mpstat.htm).

It has a list of all the 40 columns that are presented when the option
`-a` ALL is used:

```
CPU min maj mpcs mpcr dev soft dec ph cs ics bound rq push
S3pull S3grd S0rd S1rd S2rd S3rd S4rd S5rd S3hrd S4hrd S5hrd
sysc us sy wa id pc %ec ilcs vlcs lcs %idon %bdon %istol %bstol %nsp
```

us and sy are listed as the fields 27 and 28, however the command presented
by the user selects fields number 25 and 27. Close but not the same. The
only way to confirm would be to receive the output of the command from the user.

For testing I will be using the [output of `mpstat 5 1` from here](http://www.mcpressonline.com/unix-/-aix/tune-aix-for-optimal-performance.html).

```
# mpstat 5 1

System configuration: lcpu=4 ent=1.0 mode=Uncapped

cpu   min  maj  mpc  int   cs  ics   rq  mig lpa   sysc us sy wt id   pc  %ec  lcs
0 4940    0    1  632  685  268    0  320 100 263924 42 55  0  4 0.57 35.1  277
1  990    0    3 1387 2234  805    0  684 100 130290 28 47  0 25 0.27 16.6  649
2 3943    0    2  531  663  223    0  389 100 276520 44 54  0  3 0.57 34.9  270
3 1298    0    2 1856 2742  846    0  752 100  82141 31 40  0 29 0.22 13.4  650

ALL 11171    0    8 4406 6324 2142    0 2145 100 752875 39 51  0 10 1.63 163.1 1846


The second command
`mpstat -A 1 1 |            # execute command
    tr -s ' ' '|' |         # replace all spaces with (|).
    head -8 |               # select 8 first lines.
    tail -4 |               # select last four lines.
    cut -d'|' -f 25,27 |    # select fields 25 and 27
    awk -F "|" '{printf "%.0f:%.0f:",$2,$1}' |  # print the fields as integers.
    sed '$s/.$//' |             # on the last line ($), substitute the last character (.$) by nothing.
    sed -e "s/ \{1,\}$//" |     # remove trailing space(s).
    awk '{
        int a[10];
        split($1, a,":");
        printf("%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7])
    }' \
`
```

About the int: For older versions of awk, calling a function without the parentheses is equivalent to call the function on $0. int is equivalent to int($0), which is not printed, nor used. The same happens to the value of a[10].

The split sets each value of the command in a[i]. Then, all values of a[i] are printed as decimals.

The equivalent, and way simpler is:

```
Command #2
`mpstat -A 1 1 |
 awk -v firstline=6 -v cpus=4 '
        BEGIN{start=firstline-1; end=firstline+cpus;}
        NR>start && NR<end   {printf( ":%d:%d", $27,$25)}'
`
```